# How to join array elements into string with commas & ampersand?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, formatting

In my program given an array of hashes of the name. I want to return a string formatted as a list of names separated by commas except for the last two names, which should be separated by an ampersand.

For e.g.

```
list([{ name: 'Bart' }, { name: 'Lisa' }, { name: 'Maggie' }]);
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

list([{ name: 'Bart' }, { name: 'Lisa' }]);
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

list([{ name: 'Bart' }]);
// returns 'Bart'

list([]);
// returns ''
```

For that, I am mapping values of an array of object using map function and using the slice to extract the last two values of the array and then using `toString` to convert it into string and then using `split("&")` to add ampersand between last two elements but I'm not getting output according to expectation.

code:

```
function list(names){
   let result = names.map(value => value.name);
   return result.slice(-2).toString().split('&');
}

list([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]);
```

Comment: What's the question you meant to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit tricker than that, since you'll have to separate out the final name in the list from the rest initially, then `join` the rest. If there *are* any in the rest, then concatenate the joined string with `' and '`, else return the final name only:

```js
function list(people){
  const names = people.map(({ name }) => name);
  const finalName = names.pop();
  return names.length
  ? names.join(', ') + ' & ' + finalName
  : finalName;
}

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])) // returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'
console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])) // returns 'Bart & Lisa'
console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])) // returns 'Bart'
```

Note that the input is *not* an array of `name`s - it's an array of objects that need to be mapped to `names` later, so you might name your variables more precisely and give `list` an argument of `people` (or something like that) rather than `names`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `pop` the last item from the array, `join` the remaining items using a comma and then append the last item with an ampersand. Updated code:

```js
function list(names) {
   if (names.length === 0) return '';
   if (names.length === 1) return names[0].name; 
   let result = names.map(value => value.name);
   let lastName = result.pop();
   return result.join(', ') + ' & ' + lastName;
}

let string = list([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]);

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thanks @kfedorov91 for answering. but what does reult.pop() do ? does it remove all elements from array ?

Comment: @Riya yes, `result.pop()` removes the last item from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Only enter code herey two condition :

- if only one name in the list
- or more than one name in list

```js
function myCustomList(persons){
  names = persons.map(({ name }) => name);
  lastName = names.pop();
  return names.length ? names.join(', ') + ' & ' + lastName : lastName;
}
//watch your answer in alert box

alert(myCustomList([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; `join` is the missing ingredient and is perfect for delimited lists.

Edge cases are when there is only one or no names in the list and require extra conditionals to handle. A couple other answers in this thread don't handle empty lists gracefully.

```js
const list = names =>
  names.slice(0, -1).map(e => e.name).join(", ") +
  (names.length > 1 ? " & " : "") +
  (names.length ? names[names.length-1].name : "")
;

console.log(list([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]));
console.log(list([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]));
console.log(list([{name: 'Bart'}]));
console.log(list([]));
```

That said, I'd probably generalize the function to avoid the hardcoded `.name` key, adding that as a separate preprocessing step:

```js
const commaJoin = a => 
  a.slice(0, -1).join(", ") +
  (a.length > 1 ? " & " : "") +
  (a.length ? a.at(-1) : "")
;

const nameToList = list => commaJoin(list.map(e => e.name));

console.log(nameToList([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]));
console.log(nameToList([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]));
console.log(nameToList([{name: 'Bart'}]));
console.log(nameToList([]));

console.log(commaJoin(["foo", "bar"]));
```